# Go doc for simple hello world program

Tags: go, godoc

How to write a go program such that it has a simple doc for it

example

```
package HelloWorld

import "fmt"

func HelloWorld() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

after making changes for this code if exec

```
go doc <needed command>
```

it should print

```
this is a hello world program
```

Comment: FYI: in Golang, functions names (constants, types, packages, and functions) are `CamelCased`, not `Snake_cased`. Package names are generally brief (a single word), and lower-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the documentation in a comment before the package declaration, leaving no empty lines between them.

For example:

```
/*
This is a hello world program.
*/
package main
```

Then provide the package to `go doc`, like this:

```
go doc path/to/your/package
```

Output will be:

```
This is a hello world program.
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking for.
But you can describe a go package like this and `go doc` will pick up on this.

```golang
// this is some description for the package
package mypackage
```

You could then view the documentation in the browser using

```sh
godoc -http=:6060
```

There are many tricks which can be done using GoDoc which are described in this [Github Repository - godoc-tricks](https://github.com/fluhus/godoc-tricks/blob/master/doc.go) or this [blog post by the Go team](https://go.dev/blog/godoc).